# How to make z-index for area lines in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

i have chart like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nbLjtLjy/)

Here is my plotOptions and Series

```
plotOptions: {
        area: {
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
            states: {
                hover: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        }
    }


series: [{
        data: [9.9, 51.5, 66.4, 49.2, 84.0, 186.0, 15.6, 198.5, 96.4, 134.1, 105.6, 24.4],
        color: '#f8f3ee',
        lineColor: '#e6d7c2',
        fillOpacity: 1
    }, {
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        color: '#f8f3ee',
        lineColor: '#bd965d',
        lineWidth: 2,
        fillOpacity: 1
    }]
```

There is 2 areas, with same fill color, same opacity: 1, and Y/X gridlines.

Is it possible somehow to set z-index for area line?

Here is what i am need. [image](http://take.ms/qgr3K)

So both area lines should have z-index higher than area fill, and higher than gridlines. But gridlines should have z-index higher than area fill

Thank you.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue in the end? I'm encountering the same problem.

Comment: @engelen, i am afraid no. I leave it as is. But maybe plugin have been updated during this time, so they make this feature. Check out documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse! And they haven't, unfortunately :-).

Answer (score 2):

You must use the series.index option.

See: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.index

This is the description:

> index: NumberSince 2.3.0
>
> The index of the series in the chart, affecting the internal index in the chart.series array, the visible Z  index as well as the order in the legend.

An example of code

```
series: [{
    index:2,
    data: [9.9, 51.5, 66.4, 49.2, 84.0, 186.0, 15.6, 198.5, 96.4, 134.1, 105.6, 24.4],
    color: '#f8f3ee',
    lineColor: '#e6d7c2',
    fillOpacity: 1
}, {
    index: 1,
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    color: '#f8f3ee',
    lineColor: '#bd965d',
    lineWidth: 2,
    fillOpacity: 1
}]
```

A jsfiddle showing how to use it.

http://jsfiddle.net/vaa2uqpt/1/

Comment: thank you sir ! May I add that you can set only the "background" serie area to index:-1 to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

When removing the opacity, the chart looks like your image:

```
series: [{
    data: [9.9, 51.5, 66.4, 49.2, 84.0, 186.0, 15.6, 198.5, 96.4, 134.1, 105.6, 24.4],
    color: '#f8f3ee',
    lineColor: '#e6d7c2'
    //fillOpacity: 1
}, {
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    color: '#f8f3ee',
    lineColor: '#bd965d',
    lineWidth: 2
    //fillOpacity: 0.1
}]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nbLjtLjy/1/

Or do I miss something?

Comment: Hi. I tested this option. Here is few things, grid is on the chart, so it "cut" lines. Second is - bottom zone where both charts is fill, have more color than upper chart. So i am trying to find method which allow me make area fill z-index to 1, gridlines to 2, and area lines to 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Renderer which allows to print custom elements on charts.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text